# To use multithreading, is Command pattern more useful than Decorator pattern?

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, decorator, command-pattern

Having seen how [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) was used in a previous project, I can understand how it can be useful in multithreaded (parallel) programming, because Commands can be executed in different threads. When data needs to be passed between commands, the data can be stored in a shared memory and a pointer (or handle) to that data can be passed to an invoker on a differeht thread.

However, Decorator pattern seems to have the restriction that everything must happen on a single thread, because the decorator has to call the delegate directly, implying they must be on the same thread.

Is my understanding of this limitation correct? On the contrary, is it possible to run decorator on multiple threads?

---

What I'm trying to implement is a pipeline that processes a stream of data.

- To implement as Command pattern, its `execute` method would take two arguments: a buffer for input and a buffer for output.
- To implement as Decorator pattern, its `getdata` method would call its delegate to get the result of the previous step, apply its own processing, and return the result to the caller.

However after I have implemented it in both styles, I found that each has limitations that wasn't clear to me originally.

- When using the Command pattern, I can start accepting more input data by using a new buffer, while the earlier buffers are being processed by some Commands running in separate work threads. I can't seem to do this with Decorator pattern.
- When using the Decorator pattern, the decorator can make any number of calls to its delegate and be able to combine the results into one chunk. It can also split data, by making one big request, cache it, and then returning pieces of it. When I use Command pattern with one input buffer and one output buffer, there cannot be any combination or splitting of results.

Comment: huh. I fail to see the connection between decorator and threading. These are orthogonal concepts in my view. How does one 'call' or 'execute' a decorator? Decorators are a way to [`add behaviour to an existing object dynamically`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Comment: Decorators can be used to make any class thread safe, by wrapping objects into synchronized methods. In any case usefulness of a pattern is topic too subjective to get an answer here.

Comment: @sehe: there are some frameworks where the bulk of processing is carried out by decorators, by performing additional processing on the data returned from its delegate. I know that decorators (as described originally) are supposed to be lightweight (they provide a good syntax for the users), so maybe the heavyweight decorator shouldn't be caller a decorator?

Comment: sehe is correct.  The pattern exists to extend the behavior of an existing object.  Period.  The decorator does not provide "good syntax" it should provide transparent syntax to the user.  "Lightweight" and "heavyweight" are not relevant.    Whether or not multithreading is suitable is determined by the process, not the pattern.  If the process lends itself to multi-part and typically asynchronous execution. MT can be useful.  If not, MT is not useful.  The Decorator pattern does not imply anything about the process, merely that it can be extended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you can run Decorators on any thread is implementation defined :)

If your decorators are thread safe... yes. If not: add synchronisation. This might undermine your performance.

However, in my view, it makes a lot of sense for decorators to mostly occupy themselves with the object they are decorating, and only little bits of context/state outside that. The object being decorated here, obviously should be threadsafe (or aware) in the first place, or it would have the same problem even without the decorator.

Perhaps this is what you call 'lightweight' decorators. If your decorators are heavyweight (in that they 'use the world' to do their job) there's definitely going to be synchronisation required. This may even lead to performance bottlenecks.

But **fundamentally** *nothing precludes a (in general) decorator from being executed on any thread you want*.